# Error connecting to Azure Key Vault from SQL Server Management Studio for Always Encrypt

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I am trying to set up SQL Server Always Encrypt but when I try to use Azure for the Master Key I get an error in the SSMS wizard when trying to connect to the Azure Key Vault.

I try to sign into the key vault from the following screen:

[image]

When I click 'Sign In...' and select my username, I get the following error:
[image]

There a few key vaults up in Azure and I have full rights to one of them. Do I need the same rights to all of them? Is there some other set of permissions I need?

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the `Show details` button yet to see the details? What versions of .NET Framework do you have installed on the computer? Accessing the Azure Key Vault requires at least .NET Framework 4.6.1 (technically 4.6), using Always Encrypted with Secure Enclaves requires at least .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [Using the Azure Key Vault Key Store Provider for Always Encrypted | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlsecurity/using-the-azure-key-vault-key-store-provider-for-always-encrypted#azure-key-vault)

> To use keys with Azure Key Vault, we’ll need to have all of `create`,
> `get, sign, verify, wrapKey, and unwrapKey` permissions.  These
> permissions are required for creating a new column master key in Azure
> Key Vault and using it to set up encryption via SQL Server Management
> Studio.

> **Note:** The permissions listed above are required for using the **Always Encrypted** wizard in SQL Server Management Studio.  If you wish
> to use the "New Column Master Key" window (accessed via right-clicking
> on the "Always Encrypted Keys" folder under "Security"), you'll also
> need the `list` permission.

[image]

2. The reason can be backward compatibility.Try to connect to the latest or the compatible version of Sql management studio.And make sure The combined length for the key vault name and key name cannot exceed 94 characters.

- Make sure sql server is v2019 or later ,As Always Encrypted with
  secure enclaves, introduced in SQL Server 2019 (15.x), addresses the
  limitation by enabling pattern matching, comparison operators and   indexing on columns using randomized encryption. In previous version
  randomized encryption is not supported.

Or try by reinstalling .net version 4.7.2 as in comment.

3. Usually soft delete is enabled by default in azure portal.Check if there is issue with soft delete. See  [similar Issue (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5a67e5e8-c683-478c-911d-a490e8e941f4/ssms-throws-exception-when-configuring-always-encrypted-to-use-key-vault) and check if the key has expiration date and has expired.The expiration date must not be set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by installing Sql Server Management Studio v19.0. current version was Sql server management studio v18. My error is as below. if it is throwing in the azure connection, you can make encryption without any problems by installing the version.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maTIH.png)